# How to use socket.write inside a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, .net, sockets

```js
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function(connection) { 
   console.log('client connected');
   connection.on('end', function() {
      console.log('closed');
   });
  // connection.write('100');
   connection.pipe(connection);
});
server.listen(5001, function() { 
  console.log('server is listening');
});
function addInput(){
    var value = document.getElementById("textId").value;
    console.log(value);
    document.getElementById("textId").value="";
    //connection.write(value);
}
```

I want to send data to the client in the button function addinput, but I can't send it, how can I use socket.write in the function

Comment: There can be lots of connections. Which one do you want to write to?

Answer (score 0):

Is that code that you commented (`connection.write(value);`) supposed to work?
You won't be able to make it work since `connection` is only within the scope of the function you wrote into `var server`.

Other than that, to get your server to do anything you'll have to make a request to it, possibly with `net.createConnection()` (check doc here: https://nodejs.org/api/net.html). I'm not seeing any code in your example that would do that so far.